# How to achieve adobe all updates from adobe server?

Tags: adobe, patch

Currently I am working with WSUS and getting all Microsoft patches from server. Similar way how I can achieve all the updates(patches) from adobe ?

- Is it any option with WSUS to get all 3 rd party updates (Non-Microsoft, included all adobe updates).?

Please help me regarding it.

What I have tried:

Performing one time updates from adobe server using by AUSST. But here I am thinking I can’t achieve all the adobe updates .. It is supporting only CS products.

By using AUSST (Adobe updates server set up tool ) first time updates are taking too much space in server. Both windows & Mac OS updates will be downloaded. I don't know how to get only windows updates from adobe server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the AUSST server from Adobe does not have what you are looking for.

Currently (latest version 4.1.1.202) it does not let you choose what OS (Win/Mac) for your updates, and it also does not cater for the Adobe free products such as Reader, AIR, or Flashplayer.

There seems to be little interest from Adobe in developing a better way to manage the AUSST server nor including their non Creative Cloud products - you will need to find another solution.